# Asp.net Core crashes when editing cshtml while running

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm getting

> MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Cci.IMethodReference Microsoft.Cci.ICustomAttribute.Constructor(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitContext)'.

when trying to edit a cshtml file while ASP.NET Core solution is running.

How to get the error:

1. Run solution
2. Edit cshtml file
3. Go to link where cshtml is showed
4. Error is showing

I have Visual Studio Professional 2017 version 15.9.4

.NET Core version is 2.1

Comment: Also getting this when running .net core 2.2. Use to happen periodically and now when I've enabled `.AddRazorOptions(options => options.AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange = true);` make a change, refresh the page, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit for me was a reference to Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common v2.10.0 in the web project. Downgrading that reference to v2.8.0 should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all nuGet packages is supported with 'Asp Net Core'. Uninstalling packages with only .Net support did the trick for me.